# Can't install CLI tool to be used globally in the terminal on Windows

Tags: windows, bash, rust, binaryfiles, rust-cargo

I've made a Rust CLI tool and want to provide download instructions for it to users.

The tool lets you run commands like `convert <some args>` and lets you convert between numbers with different bases. The key here is I'm trying to enable you running the commands with the keyword `convert` globally instead of a user having to be in the project directory and run `cargo run <args>` or `./main <args>`.

My `Cargo.toml` looks like this:

```
[package]
name = "converter_cli"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]

[[bin]]
name = "convert"
path = "src/main.rs"
```

Currently, after some research, I've written these instructions which **work** for my computer (Mac M1):

1. Make sure you have Rust installed on your system. If you don't, [use this link](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install).
2. Clone the repo: `git clone https://github.com/mattrltrent/base_converter`.
3. In the project directory, run `cargo build --release`.
4. In the project directory, run `cargo install --path .` (don't miss the ending `.`).
5. You should now be able to run the tool globally. To be sure, check if you can run `convert version`.

However, I've ran these instructions on a Windows PC and I get the error "Invalid drive specification", when trying to run `convert <args>`.

Is there a better way to make this distributable (without publishing it as a Cargo crate) for Linux, Windows, and MacOS in one unified way? Or if not, why don't these instructions work for Windows?

If relevant, my file structure is as follows:

```
assets
-> <random image assets>
src
-> conversions.rs
-> errors.rs
-> main.rs
target
.gitignore
Cargo.lock
Cargo.toml
README.md
```

Comment: I suggest you distribute the compiled program (e.g. the .exe created in the target folder for a windows target) instead of forcing all of your users to install a complete Rust toolchain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The naming issue

The name is overshadowed by system-builtin:

`convert` is already a valid command:

> Converts a disk from one disk type to another.
>
> - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/convert

Here are some solutions:

1. Reference your application via full path *(ugly, but should do the trick)*
2. Specifically alias your application on Windows
3. Rename your application to a somewhat more unique name

### Distributing

Distributing is quite a big topic.

Think about how you usually install new software. Behaviour differs from not only people but the used OS, restrictions of the user (admin rights), ...

#### **Provide a compiled program**

(as @PaulDempsey already suggested)
(in general most people are used to that)

##### where

- as release in GitHub
- on a dedicated webpage
- on some software portal / app store

##### how

- simply the binary (aka `*.exe`)
- wrapped in an installer

#### Add your package to package manager repositories

there are a bunch of package managers to consider and there are different approaches to get ones own application in there but there are e.g.:

- brew for macOS
- apt, pacman and many more for Linux
- choco for Windows
- ...

Some of them might compile stuff for you others you might simply ship executables with.

#### Convert your steps into an install script

Most of your steps can easily be converted to a shell and/or batch script so the user can simply run `install.sh` and everything is good to go. This way you can automatically differentiate behaviors on different systems.